# RequestError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentClientRequest state NODEJS MSSQL(7.11.2)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

> RequestError: Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentClientRequest state

I am using NodeJS MSSQL(7.11.2)

I get this error when using transaction and requests but not when using just the query.

```
const result = await sql.query("select * from TagDefinition"); //this works
```

I read the documentation but I can't seem to find a way to address that.

Do you have an idea on how I could address that?

I stripped the code to a minimum and the exception seems to get fired off at

```
request.query("select * from TagDefinition"); //this sends the exception
```

```
await sql.connect(this.sqlConfig);
const result = await sql.query("select * from TagDefinition");
        
console.log(result);

const transact = new sql.Transaction();

await transact.begin(e=>{
console.log(e)
      const request = new sql.Request(transact);
      request.query("select * from TagDefinition");
      transact.commit(e=>{console.log(e)});
      });
```

Comment: Have you tried using `transact.commit(e=>{console.log(e)});` inside the completion handler for `request.query(...)`? Ref: [Transaction](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#transaction)

Comment: Thank you It worked. I'll give the doc a better look next time!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/users/390122

```
        const t = new sql.Transaction()
        t.begin(e =>{
            const r = new sql.Request(t)
            r.query("INSERT INTO[Permission] ([Name]) VALUES('test')", e=>{
                t.commit(e=>{
                    console.log("it worked")
                })
            })
        })
```

this worked.

For future reference, I also tried this

```
         const transact = new sql.Transaction();
         await transact.begin()
         const request = new sql.Request()
         request.query("INSERT INTO[Permission] ([Name]) VALUES('testt')");
         transact.commit();
```

and this

```
        //sql.connect(this.sqlConfig);
        const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlConfig);
        const connectionPool = await pool.connect()
        
        const t =  connectionPool.transaction()
        await t.begin();
        const r = t.request();
        await r.query("INSERT INTO[Permission] ([Name]) VALUES('testt')");
        await t.commit();
        console.log("worked ")
```

And they both work too.